# How do I serialize a .NET object into Azure Blob Storage without using a temporary file?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, azure, azure-storage

I want to store a .NET object into Azure Blob Storage.

Currently I serialize it into an XML file using `TextWriter` (`episodeList` is the object I want serialized):

```
XmlAttributeOverrides overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
XmlAttributes Xmlattr = new XmlAttributes();
Xmlattr.XmlRoot = new XmlRootAttribute("EPISODES");
overrides.Add(typeof(List<EpisodeData>), Xmlattr);
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<EpisodeData>), overrides);
TextWriter textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\movie.xml");
serializer.Serialize(textWriter, episodeList);
textWriter.Close();
```

and then upload the file into Blob Storage:

```
CloudBlobClient blobStorage = createOrGetReferenceOfBlobStorage(folderName);
string uniqueBlobName = string.Format("{0}/{1}", folderName, fileName);
CloudBlockBlob blob = clouBblockBlobPropertySetting(blobStorage, uniqueBlobName, ".txt");
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(blob.OpenWrite()))
{
    writer.Write(content);
}
```

Is it possible to somehow skip the temporary file so that the XML is directly uploaded into Azure Blob Storage?

Comment: Is it possible to specify the bloob path instad of C:\movie.xml

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do the following. Create a `MemoryStream` instance and use `XmlSerializer.Serialize(Stream stream)` to serialize the object into the memory stream, then "rewind" the stream to beginning using `Seek()`. Then you call `CloudBlob.UploadFromStream()` to upload the stream contents to the blob.