# Share a SQL Server CE database in Azure Web and Worker roles

Tags: c#, entity-framework, azure, sql-server-ce

I'm trying to use a SQL Server CE database in Azure Web and Worker role and use it with EF. I have installed [`EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact` (v4.3.6)](http://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework.SqlServerCompact/4.3.6) and seems to work fine on the worker role. (which puts data in the database.)

Although when I try to read the data from my Web Role, it doesn't seem to recognize the database created by the worker role, and creates a new DB.

Database seems to be created by the worker role at `\Debug\roles\WorkerRoleName\approot`.

What is the best place to create the DB ? (Web role's App_Data ? or a blob storage location ?) and how do I configure EF so it looks in the same place no matter which role I ask the data from ?

If this is not possible with SQL Server CE, what other options do I have ? (don't want to use SQL Azure or table storage)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find SQL Server CE to not be viable for you, as it's a locally-installed database. I'm not sure if you've tested with multiple instances of your worker role, but you should find that these instances will not see each others' data (every instance is its own virtual machine). SQL Server CE is going to store its database file (the `.sdf` file?) in a local folder of the instance. Without some type of file-sharing set up, you won't be able to access this file from anywhere other than the instance it's installed on. And before you go exploring something like SMB, you should think about how SQL Server CE works, and if it would even support multiple database engines trying to read/write the same file.

I'm not sure why you want to avoid SQL Database (formerly known as SQL Azure), as it is db-as-a-service and may be accessed by all of your role instances, whether web or worker (or from anywhere else). Table Storage is something entirely different and not a SQL-based data store, so that makes sense.

One other option is to consider running SQL Server in a virtual machine, as SQL Server supports multiple clients just like SQL Database. There's a SQL Server image in the Virtual Machine gallery that you can use to spin up the database. You could then secure the connection from your cloud service to your SQL virtual machine either with a virtual network or an IP-ACL'd endpoint allowing only your cloud service's IP address to access it.

Comment: @marc_s Windows Azure's database is now known as SQL Database (see [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/services/sql-database/) for more info). This is why I called it SQL Database and *not* SQL Server Database (which effectively changes its meaning from *database-as-a-service* to *standalone database*). The OP referred to SQL Database as its legacy name, *SQL Azure*. Ergo... I removed your edit that renamed it.

Comment: I would label it `SQL Azure` - that's clear. `SQL database` is a contradiction - SQL is just the query language, not a product. And it's most definitely SQL **Server** CE - not just SQL CE.

Comment: I want to avoid SQL Azure to minimize the cost. Running SQL in a VM doesn't help either.. Are there any other options I missed ? If not I'll have to use SQL Azure to accomplish my work.

Comment: @Madushan - Blob and Table storage are very affordable (under 10 cents/GB/month), but you'll need to do your own serialization if storing .net objects to blobs. Here's [another SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11033739/how-do-i-serialize-a-net-object-into-azure-blob-storage-without-using-a-tempora) that answers that particular question. Not sure how much you're storing, but a 1GB SQL Database instance is just $10 monthly, a small fraction of your role instance cost.

Comment: +1 use SQL Database.  It's quick, secure, has good tooling support and resilience. All for $10 a month.  Its cheap and you already know how to use it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help. I have switched to SQL Azure, as I couldn't find a way to cut corners for my use case. :)